# Не грузятся заголовки html после session_start()

Tags: php, html

После включения механизма сессий, перестают подгружаться внешние файлы css, js и т.д. Какие могут быть варианты?

```
<?php
     session_start();   
 ?>   
<html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!--common libs-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <!--custom-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
    <title></title>  
    <script>
        <?php
            if (!isset($_SESSION['page'])){        
                echo 'sendRequest({action:"view"})';
            }
        ?>    
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пути проверь.

Comment: Есть какая-нибудь диагностика в логе или броузере ?
Попробуйте поставить `error_reporting (E_ALL)` до старта сессий.

Comment: Проблема была из-за двух пробелов перед <?php. Сессии выдавали ошибку "headers already sent, следовательно, потянули за собой потерю заголовков.

Comment: Странно что вы сами сразу не убедились в том что у вас нет лишних символов перед `session_start()`

Comment: В приведенном выше коде пробелов перед `<?php` совершенно не видно, поэтому я в своем ответе предположил, что вело в "невидимом" невооруженным взглядом BOM

Comment: В сообщении пробелов не было, про сообщение ошибки вы не писали. Так что ничего странного).

Comment: Согласен, это факт, но это произошло из-за форматирования, видимо я просто довел два пробела до четырех.

Answer (score 1):

Файл случайно не UTF8 с BOM, если да - то BOM из файла убрать